# Flow of ions in postsynaptic potentials

Tags: neuroscience

My understanding of postsynaptic potentials is that excitatory neurotransmitters cause Excitatory postsynaptic potentials (EPSPs) and inhibitory neurotransmitters cause inhibitory postsynaptic potentials (IPSPs) by triggering ion channels in the postsynaptic cell. My questions is, which ions flow in which direction in each of these scenarios?

Comment: What have you searched and what have you found so far? We expect questions to include some details/background of the problem to be solved.

Comment: I found a lot of sources talking about the flow of specific ions across the concentration gradient but I couldn't find anything on the direction. Was just hoping someone here could explain it but I figured it out and posted the answer.

Comment: @AliceD so let me get this straight, you yourself couldn’t find an answer to this question on the forum, but because my understanding isn’t as sophisticated as you’d like the question needs to be removed? What is the point of that? Why are you gatekeeping my understanding of the topic on a forum dedicated to educating people on technical questions about the subject? My question was very specific, I asked which ions flow in which direction in two different scenarios. The link you provided didn’t answer my question.

Comment: Hi Rider, I understand your concerns. We just want to maintain the site's quality in terms of the questions asked and the answers provided. Both your Q and A don't include references to credible sources. The Help Center provides useful information on how to ask questions, but in this case the question is so basic you can find the answer readily on the internet. When I typed in '*flow of ions during action potential*' in Google, the first Wiki hit already gave me the answer in the site's preview in Google on my machine.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it lacks research efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excitatory neurotransmitters released into the synaptic cleft cause sodium channels to open in the postsynaptic neuron. The concentration gradient subsequently pulls sodium ions into the cell, depolarizing it and increasing the likelihood of an action potential occurring. Inhibitory  neurotransmitters cause Chloride channels to open; subsequently the electrochemical gradient causes negatively charged chloride ions to rush into cell, in turn hyperpolarizing it and decreasing the likelihood of an action potential of occurring.

### Further Reading

Alberts, B., Johnson, A., Lewis, J., Raff, M., Roberts, K., & Walter, P. (2002). Ion Channels and the Electrical Properties of Membranes. In:  *Molecular Biology of the Cell*. 4th edition. New York: Garland Science https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK26910/